# Перенаправление с RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Приветсвую.

Помогите, пожалуйста:
На сайте есть страницы вида
http://site.com/content/dalshe-idet-tekst

надо в них "content" заменить на "stream"

http://site.com/stream/dalshe-idet-tekst

С этим ведь RewriteRule поможет ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `RewriteRule ^content/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ stream/$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Ну или как вариант:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /stream/$1 [R=301, L]
```